# images on github won't load

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm very new to coding and github. i just want to host my portfolio

So I'm trying to set up my portfolio with github.

at first it will load but when I log out from my pc the images wont load anymore.

I used wordpress static link to edit my portfolio then I hosted it at github.

but when it is hosted the images are fine but layer it wont load anymore.

here's my repo

https://github.com/jamestumarao/jamestumarao

Comment: You're not trying to serve images from your local PC are you? How have you uploaded them? You mention both GitHub and WordPress - which are you using? I'm not sure they work together. If it is Pages, can you point us at your repo?

Comment: I'm very very new to github and I don't have much codes experience.
yes I uploaded all the files to the respiratory

Comment: btw here's my repo

https://github.com/jamestumarao/jamestumarao

Comment: No it isn't: your GitHub pages are this one: https://github.com/jamestumarao/jamestumarao.github.io How are you generating that from WordPress? I think that's where you're going wrong. Your index.html there says it's been generated by a website copier, and immediately tries to redirect you to a page that doesn't exist.

Comment: I designed and edited my website port on wordpress using wampserver.

then I hosted it in github. but it seems the images won't load later on.

I'm very new to this and I badly need your help thank you

Comment: The process you're using to generate the static version from WordPress has gone wrong: the only HTML there says "Local index - HTTrack Website Copier". So you'll need to fix that. I don't know Simply Static; it's possible it doesn't like that your WordPress site is in a subdirectory rather than at the localhost root, but I'd be surprised if that was it. Your best bet is going to be to work through the Simply Static process again and if it's generating bad output then try a different plugin or see if they can help you.

Comment: I've just spotted the jamesga.github.io repository - this is much more like it, and broadly works for me if I run it locally. That's not going to be served though because that's not your user name. Rename that to jamestumararo.github.io? However there are still ~7 links that still say "localhost/jamestumaro" that you probably have to edit manually at this point, and the contact form isn't going to work on a static WordPress site because it again you can see it tries to post to localhost.

Comment: Oh thank you for that, that might be my mistake thank you

Comment: hello there, honestly I dont know whats happening. and I don't know what you mean by editing it manually. I did rename try look jamestumarao.github.io it works right? but later not

Comment: James can you get any other free template and try to build in instead of downloading webpage from HTTrack. If you have not any programming knowledge try webpage composers, they will help you to build awesome website by dragng and droping. I'm recommending Mobirise,

Comment: Oh - that's not what I meant. Your jamestumarao.github.io repo needs to be the static version of the site, not the WordPress installation (you can call that anything). It needs to have an index.html and a wp-content folder, like the repo you had called jamesga. However that one still had a lot of references to http://localhost/jamestumarao which wouldn't work: what I meant was that you'd have to open index.html in an editor and change those yourself to jamestumarao.github.io, since HTTrack didn't get them right. Some were escaped URLs so search for all mentions of 'localhost'.

Comment: But even then there are things you don't need and won't work. The feed and comments/feed folders won't work so you can delete them and remove the references to them from index.html. Ditto wp-json, since there's no real REST API behind the scenes now. Ditto the contact form: that tries to post to a REST API endpoint so won't work in the static version. And so on. If Simply Static doesn't do this for you then you might have to edit index.html yourself to fix it. Try opening the final site in a browser with the JavaScript console open and check you don't get any errors.